# How to pass array of objects from parent to child and loop both key value pairs in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass an array of objects from parent to child. And I am trying to loop the array of objects to show both key value pairs of an Object. But I am not getting the output what I am expecting.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Parent from './Parent/Parent';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <Parent></Parent>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Parent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Parent.css';
import Child from '../Child/Child';


const Parent = () => {
    const studentsList = [{ name: 'James', location: 'Willington' }, { name: 'Thomas', location: 'Auckland' }]
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='parentData'>
                        <Child list={studentsList}></Child>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';

const Child = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    {props.list.map((currentValue, index) => <li key={index}>{currentValue.name && currentValue.location} </li>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child
```

I am expecting output like this

James Willington
Thomas Auckland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Child.js, you have added && between currentValue.name and currentValue.location in

.

This needs to be changed to :

{currentValue.name + " " + currentValue.location}